# How to get getElementsByTagNameNS content?

Tags: php, dom, rss

I am trying to read and parse an RSS feed. The header of the RSS feed is the following:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:content="http://www.mywebsite.com" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" >
```

I successfully retrieved both `<title>` and `<link>` from items but I can't seem to find a way to retrieve `<content:encoded>` childs. That's what I tryed so far:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);

....

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($x as $item) {
    $link = $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $content = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.mywebsite.com', 'encoded')->item(0);
    echo ("<p><a href='" . $link. "'>" . $title . "</a></p><p>" . $content . "</p>");
}

?>
```

As you can imagine `$content` is empty even if I try to get the `nodeValue` attribute, what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you need to reeinvent the wheel? Why not use SimplePie to parse the RSS??

Comment: My server is behind a proxy, does SimplePie allow me to set it up during request? Anyway I am using DomDocument here, I don't think I am reinventing the wheel at all.

Comment: When I say reinvent the wheel I mean you'll need to code everything from scratch to get those values. I've never tested SimplePie with a proxy, but I think it is possible. Have a look at it [link](http://www.simplepie.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using SimpleXmlElement:

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($s);

foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {

    $content = $entry->children("content", true);
    echo "<p>".$content->encoded."</p>";
}
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

**The Tag name here is "encoded".**

Just use

```
$content => $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue
```